# How to view a System::String with OutputDebugString?

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, outputdebugstring

I am trying to debug a value that is `System::String`. As I am using Visual Studio, I would normally use `OutputDebugString` or its variants to see the strings, but `System::String` aren't natively compatible with `OuputDebugString`.

How do I convert a `System::String` to a value that `OuputDebugString` can print? Or an alternative tool for viewing System::string values?

In case it matters, this is specifically a `System::String^` variable.

Comment: my work around to assign the value I care about to a variable, so that I can view it in the debugger.

Comment: Have you tried the immediate window: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2022

Comment: You can try: `pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wchar_str = PtrToStringChars(system_str); OutputDebugString(wchar_str);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System::Diagnostics::Trace::WriteLine(L"Your message");
```

or:

```
String^ s = gcnew String(L"Your message");
System::Diagnostics::Trace::WriteLine(s);
```

`Trace` class is internally implemented using `OutputDebugString`. If you need to use `OutputDebugString` directly, you can use `PtrToStringChars` already mentioned in another answer.

Additional way:

```
String^ s = gcnew String(L"Your message\n");
std::wstring ws = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(s);
OutputDebugStringW(ws.c_str());
```

Comment: note that `System::Diagnostic` should be `System::Diagnostics`. Can't suggest this as an edit because it is too small of an edit

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment above:

You can use `PtrToStringChars` to get the string characters you can feed into `OutputDebugString`.
From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/convert-systemstring-char):

> PtrToStringChars gives you an interior pointer to the actual String
> object. If you pass this pointer to an unmanaged function call, you
> must first pin the pointer to ensure that the object does not move
> during an asynchronous garbage collection process

**Usage example in your case:**

```
#include <vcclr.h>

System::String ^ system_str = gcnew System::String("abcd");
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wchar_str = PtrToStringChars(system_str);
OutputDebugString(wchar_str);
```

**Note:** the pinned pointer `wchar_str` will be released when it goes out of scope.